# JS : Button issue grabbing my own URL before a fetch event

Tags: javascript

I dont know why, but it seems like my **search-btn** grabs my own URL (and THEN he grabs the fetch requested URL).
I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux ( /w Ubuntu ), and I think it's impossible to install Postman there.

Any advice on how to remove my own URL from the click event ?

**Error message in console :** ( when I click the button )

```
_script.js:14 GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/next/19_weekend/modalnested/www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=egg 404 (Not Found)
_VM2097:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Im talking about this :
**http://127.0.0.1:5501/next/19_weekend/modalnested/www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=egg 404 (Not Found)**

Why does it started like this ? :
**http://127.0.0.1:5501/next/19_weekend/modalnested/**

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class="meal-search-box">
  <input type ="text" class = "search-control" placeholder="enter a meal" id="search-input">
   <button type ="submit" class ="search-btn btn" id="search-btn">
     <i class ="fas fa-search"></i>
   </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript Code :**

```
const searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');


var x = document.getElementById("search-btn").value;
console.log(x)

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', getMealList);

function getMealList() {
  let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();
  console.log(searchInputTxt.length)
  fetch('www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=egg')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm following this tutorial, and it's not inside a <form> but works for him.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opikz5x_1ak

Answer (score 2):

Use an absolute Uniform Resource Identifier (URI: so, including the protocol). If you don't, the browser interprets the url as a path of your site.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', getMealList);

function getMealList(evt) {
  if (evt.target.closest(`#search-btn`)) {
    const searchInputTxt = document.querySelector('#search-input').value.trim();
    return fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=egg')
    //            ^ protocol https
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="meal-search-box">
  <input type="text" class="search-control" placeholder="enter a meal" id="search-input">
  <button type="submit" class="search-btn btn" id="search-btn">
     <i class ="fas fa-search">search</i>
   </button>
</div>
</div>
```